# How to get event that has fired the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose that I've this:

```
<form onsubmit="Popup(this)">
```

when I press the `submit` button the `Popup` function is fired. How can I get the `submit` event and prevent it?

```
Popup: function(item)
```

Thanks.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: `return false` from `Popup` will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function( item ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  item.preventDefault();
  // rest of the code
}
```

OR

```
    $("#form_id").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // do code
            return false;
    }})
```

Comment: @user3287550 It does.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with jQuery.

```
$('form').submit(Popup); //this inside the function is the form.
                         // The first parameter is the event.
```

And make sure to return false from `Popup`

**If `Popup` isn't a constructor, use camelCase naming**

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code should work if you just modify it just a bit. Add `return` to your `Popup` method call

```
<form onsubmit="return Popup(this)">
```

And at the end of your method declaration add `return false`

```
Popup: function(item){
           // your code goes here
           return false; //add this
       }
```